# How to remove dublicate functions inside an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, filter

I have 3 functions

```
const func1 = () => {
  return 1
}
const func2 = () => {
  return 1
}
const func3 = () => {
  return 2
}
let arr = [func1, func2, func3]
```

how can I filter dublicates (`func1` and `func2`) from `arr`, so that I will have something like this `filteredArr=[()=>{return 1},()=>{return 2}]` ?

tried to stringify each of them and then use if with eval but I want to filter the array without using eval

Comment: So are you just trying to find if a function is listed twice? E.g. ```let arr = [func1, func1, func2]```?

Comment: Functions are not different than any other variables, this is a duplicate question. Please check if your question is already answered before posting.

Comment: @snnsnn It may be a duplicate or be closed as "Needs more details or clarity", but your linked question does not answer their question. It seems that they are trying to remove duplicates based on the return value or body of the functions...

Comment: I've voted to close as unclear question. What are duplicate functions? Are `let a = 0; function f() { a = 1; return 1; } function g() { a = 2; return 1; }` duplicate functions?

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the array with an additional check inside, but this requires you to call the functions.

```js
const func1 = () => {
  return 1
}
const func2 = () => {
  return 1
}
const func3 = () => {
  return 2
}

let arr = [func1, func2, func3]

const uniqueItems = arr.filter((func, index, array) =>
  index === array.findIndex(f => f() === func())
)

console.log(uniqueItems)
```

Comment: This only works if the bodies of the functions are *exactly* the same. No extra spaces; nothing must be different.

Comment: Fixed to check function results, but it's weird.

Answer (score 0):

You could use lodash library ([Docs here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniq)):

```
import _ from 'lodash';

const uniqueValues = _.uniq(arr)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question as it uses [SameValueZero](https://262.ecma-international.org/7.0/#sec-samevaluezero) comparison. OP is asking to remove duplicates based on the returned value or body of the functions, not if the are the same reference.

Comment: yeah, this will not work :( but thanks for the answer!